# CSS Positioning: Too long text string puts text beneath image, not next to

Tags: html, css, positioning

When my a text string gets too long, it goes under an image, when instead, I'd like it to just go to a new line and remain to the right of the image.  How do I make the text continue to stay to the right of the image instead of going beneath that "race2.jpg" image when it becomes too long?  I suppose it could be done with line breaks if all else fails, but is there another way?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fgGyF/

HTML:

```
<div id="rightcolumn">
<div id="supportus">
     <h6>Support Us</h6>

<div style="float: left">
    <img src="images/race2.jpg" width="180" height="360" />
</div>

<div style="float:left; text-align: left">
Test text here. And here and here and here and here and here.
</div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftcolumn {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#rightcolumn {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#twitter {
  min-height: 250px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#whatsnew {
  min-height: 500px;
  background: #f0f7cb;
  outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px
}
#supportus {
  min-height: 445px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #f0f7cb;
  outline:#FFFFFF solid thick;
}
#dianerehm {
  min-height: 200px;
  background: #f0f7cb;
  outline:#FFFFFF s
```

Comment: `<div style="float:left; text-align: left">` Remove the float left from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Assign the div with text a set width.

```
  <div style="float:left; width:140px; text-align: left">
Test text here. And here and here and here and here and here.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove some markup:

```
<div id="supportus">
    <h6>Support Us</h6>
    <img src="images/race2.jpg" width="180" height="360" style="float: left" />
    Test text here. And here and here and here and here.
</div>
```

(removed wrapper `DIVs` and put `float` on `IMG`)